# Can I delete a question and create a better one instead of editing it?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I created a nice question with a very broad problem description. I've put a lot of code samples and structured the problem well to help understanding the context. But continuing my research, I discovered that the problem was, in fact, a small jQuery issue that didn't need all that background to be solved.

I didn't know what to do. If I should:

1. Delete the entire question and write another one with the correct tags and the specific problem, or
2. Edit the question, changing tags, title, and telling that the problem was narrowed to a small jQuery matter

What would be the best option in this case?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I didn't find that at first. Though @Andrew Barber really helped me out there with his comments.

Comment: It's no problem; it's just better to have the post marked as a duplicate of another (very similar) question exists in case someone comes across *this* particular one in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the question you've formulated is so horrible, it can't be salvaged, you should try to avoid deleting it. If it can be narrowed down, while still remaining on the same basic topic, you should probably try that. However, If there are good, relevant answers, and your edit would invalidate their correctness, you probably should not edit, but post a new one.

And deletion is possibly not a good idea either way, unless, again, you think it's really bad. But it sounds like you clearly don't think that!

Comment: actually, it doesn't have any answer. But it was a broad php, html, and js question at the beginning, and became a small jquery matter. Maybe deletion should I good idea in this case, but since i think its a little strong, I'm afraid to do it.

Comment: If it has no answers and all you are doing is narrowing it down, my opinion would be to edit it, then answer it.

Comment: I still don't know the answer for it. I'll still wait for someone to answer. I also think that people could see that as an old question (like 2 days with no answer), even though it is a good question and can be answered if narrowed. Isn't it better to make a new one, so it would be "fresh".

Comment: Oh, sorry, @MauricioMoraes; For some reason I thought you said you had an answer. Still, I think narrowing the existing one would work, but I see you decided to delete. Don't agonize over it too much :) If you hesitate to delete most of the time, no one's going to complain the rare times when you do!

Comment: That's good. I don't know sometimes I think people see deleting questions as a very bad thing. In this case I'll do it. Does it make sense to say that a "fresh" question get more attention that an editted one?

Comment: @MauricioMoraes Not necessarily, no. Editing 'bumps' a question to the top of most of the question lists, and that often will garner the same attention as a new question.

Comment: Ow, well! That's good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If it is a completely different question, with different tags and a different solution...

Write a new question. If you have the solution, by all means, post an answer with the question (make sure both question and answer follow our quality and on-topicness guidelines).

If the original question has any value, keep it around. If it doesn't - delete it (if it has any answers with upvotes, the system would see that as a signal that it has value - for others, if not yourself, and will not let you delete it).

Comment: I don't have answers for that, but I believe that if I narrow it, it can have good ones. I think I'll go for delete this time, even though I think it is bad most of the times.